# Coloring petals of a polar curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

[image]

Please, how do I color each of the five petals of the following polar curve with different colors?

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{polaraxis}
     \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:360,samples=300] {cos(5*x)};
   \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative in [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

The idea is essentially the same as @mickep's answer.  Make the complete rose curve, then pick out a suitable subpath of the domain to get a petal.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
input colorbrewer-rgb
numeric n; n = 5;  % n should be odd
path rose, petal; 
rose = (for t=0 upto 179: cosd (n * t) * dir t .. endfor cycle) scaled 100;
petal = subpath (-90/n, 90/n) of rose .. cycle;
for i=1 upto n:
    fill petal rotated (360 / n * i) withcolor Spectral[n][i];
endfor
draw rose;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `lualatex`.

Answer (score 5):

You can play with the domains. I made two for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{polaraxis}
     \addplot[mark=none,blue,domain=-18:18,samples=300] {cos(5*x)};
     \addplot[mark=none,red,domain=18:54,samples=300] {cos(5*x)};
   \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is my atempt with plain Asymptote. There is `polargraph` command, but no `polaraxis` command in the module `graph` of Asymptote (also see [this link](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/2Dgraphs/generalaxis.asy) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282875/140722)), so I draw the polar axis directly.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import graph;
size(8cm);
path c1=circle((0,0),1);
path c2=circle((0,0),.5);
path c=circle((0,0),1.2);
draw(c1^^c2,gray);
draw(c);
for(int i=0; i<12; ++i){
draw((0,0)--1.3dir(30i),lightgray);
label(string(30i),1.45dir(30i));
}
label("O",(0,0),3W);
label("$1$",(1,0),SE);

pen[] d={red,orange,yellow,blue,green};
real f(real t){return cos(5t);}
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i){
path g=polargraph(f,(2i-1)*pi/10,(2i+1)*pi/10,operator..)--cycle;
filldraw(g,d[i]+opacity(.5));  
}
```

If you want to rotate the petals a bit, just use apply `rotate(30)` before the paths.

```
filldraw(rotate(30)*g,d[i]+opacity(.5));
```

[image]